# "du -h -a" not show all disk usages

Tags: debian, disk-usage

When I run `df -h`, I have the following output, indicate that /dev/sda6 which mounted on / is using 100% disk space.

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6              29G   29G   34M 100% /
```

I navigate to /,
I run

```
du -h -a --max-depth=1 | sort -h
```

to see which folder use the most spaces. I got only a result of 2.6 GB diskusage.

```
2,6G    .
1,2G    ./usr
573M    ./opt
448M    ./var
114M    ./lib
93M     ./root
87M     ./home
7,5M    ./etc
5,8M    ./sbin
5,7M    ./bin
4,3M    ./lost+found
3,6M    ./lib32
8,0K    ./dev
0       ./vmlinuz
0       ./tmp
0       ./sys
0       ./srv
0       ./selinux
0       ./proc
0       ./mnt
0       ./media
0       ./lib64
0       ./initrd.img
0       ./forcefsck
0       ./ext
0       ./dead.letter
0       ./boot
0       ./000-default-ssl
```

Running `du -h -s -x /` as suggested in the comments also shows only 2.6 GB used, where `df -h` says I have 29GB used for `/dev/sda6` which is mounted at `/`.

Where are the rest of the files?

Comment: Why did you run with `--max-depth=1`. Are you not interested in the whole file tree?  Do `du -h -s -x /` instead.

Comment: du -h -s -x / also show 2.6 GB used, where df -h says I have 29GB used for /dev/sda6 which is mounted at /

Comment: A log file that was deleted but still being filled in? `try lsof -n |egrep -w 'DEL|deleted'`. See if there's a deleted file still in use that rings a bell. Also what is the filesystem type?

Comment: @A.B I ran df -T, and it shows xfs under type. I updated my question, i posted the output of      lsof -n |egrep -w 'DEL|deleted'

Comment: well I hoped you'd look at lsof and its meaning. anyway nothing useful in this lsof. (no more idea here)

Comment: bind mount the fs to another location and then du that. `mount --bind / /mnt; du -sh /mnt`

Comment: What filesystem is it? I can mount a certain Btrfs subvolume as `/` while leaving other subvolumes completely inaccessible in the current directory tree. Still `df` reports the usage of the *whole* filesystem.